# CSS - How to prevent the DIV without content from shrinking

Tags: css

I have the following code:

```
  <div id="sub-title-div">
  Hello world
  </div>

  #sub-title-div {
    background: #FFE640;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 30px;
    width: 901px;
    height: 137px;
    line-height: 13px;
  }
```

I found that if I remove the 'Hello World', the #sub-title-div will shrink and become invisible. Is there an easy method that I can do this more elegantly?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be your doctype? It doesn't dissapear for me. See the sample page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
      #sub-title-div {
        background: #FFE640;
        position: relative;
        top: 0px;
        left: 30px;
        width: 901px;
        height: 137px;
        line-height: 13px;
      } 
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="sub-title-div">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello Moin, This is my DOCTYPE: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need to support IE6, you can use the `min-height` property.

```
#sub-title-div {
    min-height: 137px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

put `&nbsp;` when you want to remove text, then div will maintain its height

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
min-width:901px;
min-height:137px;
```

if you want to have the DIV have the same dimensions even without  content.

Answer (score 1):

Use a pseudo-element. This is similar to @iTake's answer, adding an `&nbsp;`, but it keeps the extra space out of your layout and text selections.

```html
<h1 class="no-shrink"></h1>
```

```css
.no-shrink::after {
  content: '\200B'; /* zero width space */
}
```